# How to prove this integral equality $ 2 \int _0 ^u dk f(k) \int _0 ^k dt \int _0 ^t ds f(s) = \int _0 ^u dt f(t) \int _0 ^u ds f(s) |s - t|$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration

I've spent hours trying to prove the following equality but haven't got even the feeling of success.

$$ 2 \int _0 ^u dt f(t) \int _0 ^t dk \int _0 ^k ds f(s) = \int _0 ^u dt f(t) \int _0 ^u ds f(s) |s - t|$$

, where $f(x)$ is an arbitrary function. I've confirmed this is true when $f(x) = 1$ and when $f(x) = x$, using Mathematica.

Could anyone please give me a hint?

(The equation is related to *Statistical Mechanics a set of lectures, Richard P. Feynman, (p.84)*. But just related. In the book, only the rhs appears and I'm trying to prove it from the lhs. I derived the lhs by myself whose process is too complicated to write here. Please note that I don't know if there exists a relatively easy or straightforward solution because the problem isn't a homework for students.)

Comment: This looks to be related to Cauchy's repeated integral formula.

Comment: @CameronWilliams The formula completely solved my question. Thank you very much for your accurate suggestion :)

Comment: Happy to help! Glad you got it yourself. =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me write it in mathematician's notation instead of engineer's notation:
$$
2 \int _0 ^u\left[  f(k) \int _0 ^k\left( \int _0 ^t f(s) \;ds\right) dt\right]dk = \int _0 ^u\left[ f(t) \int _0 ^u f(s) |s - t|\;ds\;\right] dt
$$
Start with half of the left side:
$$
I := \int _0 ^u\left[  f(k) \int _0 ^k\left( \int _0 ^t f(s) \;ds\right) dt\right]dk
$$
where our answer is $2I$.
Interchange $s$ and $t$
$$
I = \int _0 ^u\left[  f(k) \int _0 ^k\left( \int _s ^k \;dt\right) f(s)\;ds\right]dk
\\I = I_1 := \int _0 ^u\left[  f(k) \int _0 ^k (k-s)f(s) \;ds\right]dk
$$
Now interchange $s$ and $k$
$$
I = I_2 := \int _0 ^u\left[   f(s) \int _s ^u (k-s) f(k)\;dk \right]ds
$$
re-name the variables in $I_1$ and in $I_2$
$$
I_1 = \int _0 ^u\left[  f(t) \int _0 ^t (t-s) f(s)\;ds\right]dt
\\I_2 = \int _0 ^u\left[  f(t)  \int _t ^u (s-t)f(s) \;ds \right]dt
$$
And then add:
$$
2I = I_1+I_2 = \int _0 ^u\left[  f(t) \int _0 ^u |t-s| f(s)\;ds\right]dt
$$

Comment: Thank you. It helped me a lot :) By the way, what is the difference between mathematician's notation and that of engineer's? Only the existence of paren? And why is it favorable to use the former one?

Comment: Really just for my note: how to interchange the order of integration is explained [here](http://www.math.kobe-u.ac.jp/HOME/higuchi/h23kogi/h23kouki/mp8.pdf). In the current case, the first interchange can be done using $0 \leq s \leq t \leq k$, and the second one can be done using $0 \leq s \leq k \leq u$.

Comment: Mathematician writes $\int_a^b f(x)\;dx$.  Engineer (may) write $\int_a^b dx \;f(x)$.

Comment: I see. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In both sides there exists $\int _0 ^u dt f(t)$, so first we ignore that.

Using [Cauchy formula for repeated integration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_formula_for_repeated_integration) (suggested in [this comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3417831/how-to-prove-this-integral-equality-2-int-0-u-dk-fk-int-0-k-dt-int-0#comment7029158_3417831)), we get

$$ 2 \int _0 ^t dk \int _0 ^k ds f(s) = 2 \int _0 ^t ds f(s) (t - s) = \int _0 ^t ds f(s) (t - s) + \int _0 ^t ds f(s) (t - s).$$

Also, in relation to the rhs of the original equality,

$$ \int _0 ^u ds f(s) |s - t| = \int _0 ^t ds f(s) (t - s) + \int _t ^u ds f(s) (s - t) .$$

The first terms cancel. And, lastly, it is quite easy to show

$$ \int _0 ^u dt f(t) \int _0 ^t ds f(s) (t - s) - \int _0 ^u dt f(t) \int _t ^u ds f(s) (s - t) = 0 $$

thus the equality is true.